# Android: Can I use single InputStream for multi method?

Tags: android, file, inputstream, bufferedreader

I have some problem about using readline(). I have single inputStream it's from main class

```
          private  String url = "BoardLayoutSet/01_basic.templete";
          private InputStream boardName  = getResources().getAssets().open(url);
          Board b = new Board(boardName);
```

And I send this "boardName" is InputStream to "Board" class. In this Board.class has constructor like this code below

```
     public Board(InputStream boardName) throws IOException{                    
     int[] d = LayoutDimensions(boardName); //<----First,use InputStream         
    ....
             ......      
     build(null, boardName); //<<--Second,Use InputStream                
   }
```

First method is called by this constructor(Above).
First method it  use "InputStream" like this(Below)

```
  public  int[] LayoutDimensions(InputStream boardName) throws IOException {        
    BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(boardName));     
    L1 = reader1.readLine(); // #Basic
    L1 = reader1.readLine(); // %Level 1
    L1 = reader1.readLine(); // space line
    L1 = reader1.readLine(); // First row of board
    for (int i = 0; i < L1.length(); i++) {
        if (L1.charAt(i) != ' ') {
            x++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(L1);
    System.out.println("Width(x):" + x);
    // ////////////////
    boardName.reset();
    BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(boardName));
    L2 = reader2.readLine(); // #Basic
    L2 = reader2.readLine(); // %Level 1
    L2 = reader2.readLine(); // space line
    L2 = reader2.readLine(); // First row of board

    while (L2.length()!=0) {
        System.out.println(L2.charAt(0));
        y++;
        L2 = reader2.readLine();
    }
    System.out.println("Height(y):" + y);
    .....
            ......

    reader1.close();
    reader2.close();
    reader3.close();

    return dimensions;

    }
```

When I use  one method only .it can work. Next, I need to call Second method like this

```
   protected  void build(Random r1, InputStream boardName) throws IOException {



    if (r1==null) {
        long seed = new Random().nextLong();
        r = new Random(seed);
    } else {
        r = r1;
    }


    tTile = new Tile[depth][height][width];
    int x;
    int y;
    int z=-1;

    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(boardName));

    String L=null;
    buffer.reset();
    L = buffer.readLine();  //Basic 
    .......
            ......
            ......
```

it's error since this line>>  L=buffer.readLine(); 
I tried to swap order  : use second method before fist method . the second can use but first method is error.
I think it's problem about Inputstream so I tried to make two Inputstream but it's not better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem you already closed the input stream in the method LayoutDimensions.

This

```
reader1.close();
```

Comment: I can solve this problem .

After I call layoutdimention method .I just reset InputStream before i call build(...) method. Like this...

        public Board(InputStream boardName) throws IOException{ 
    

   int[] d = LayoutDimensions(boardName);
   
  width = d[0]; 
   height = d[1]; 
   depth = d[2];
   
   boardLayout = boardName;
   boardName.reset();
   build(null, boardName);
      
 } 

I think Java not permit access a source file from any processing of buffer in the same time.